# can't read images in asp.net core website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am having an asp.net core api project and i am trying to read images that exist in my web site but i am getting 404 not found error.

Code line below that throws an exception when executing GetStreamAsync method:

```
foreach (var item in imgUrls)
                {
                    // read from remote image drive
                    using (HttpClient c = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        using (Stream s = await c.GetStreamAsync(item))
                        {
                           // do something with the stream...
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The image url is correct, but when i try to paste it in another tab while the app is running, i don't see the image displayed in my browser. am i missing an asp.net configuration or something that prohibit content files such as images from being displayed through the api response.

Note: the imageUrls we send is FQDN urls, for example the url looks like:

http://localhost:25071/images/test.jpg

looking forward to your help.

Comment: can you paste the api code also?

Comment: You didn't post your Middleware configuration, without it we're doomed to guess

Answer (score 0):

This is how i fixed the issue, i didn't enable directory browsing in my asp.net core web api.

So i added my static files (images) folder under wwwroot and added below code in startup.cs to configure/allow directory browsing to images folder and app starts to deliver and show images.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
          // few standard lines in here.....

         // enable directory browsing
         app.UseStaticFiles();
         app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
         {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/images")
        });

        app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/images")
        });
}
```

enjoy!